# Convert list inside pandas dataframe to list variable

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, csv

I have a .csv file structured as well:

```
    chan_id   spacecraft                           anomaly_sequences
      P-1       SMAP                 [[2149, 2349], [4536, 4844], [3539, 3779]]
```

I need to convert the list of list inside the cell **anomaly_sequences** to a variable, so I can loop inside it. I did it so:

```
list_labels = df['anomaly_sequences'].values.tolist()
```

but it converted all the cell in a single list, in fact if I try to print it I see it as:

```
['[[2149, 2349], [4536, 4844], [3539, 3779]]']
```

How can I correct it?

Comment: what output do you expect?

Comment: Can you also provide the output of `print(df.dtypes)`?

Comment: @TomerS a list where its first element is [2149, 2349], its second element is [4536, 4844] etc..

Comment: @Cimbali chan_id              object
spacecraft           object
anomaly_sequences    object
dtype: object

Comment: Hmmm I asked the wrong question, that doesn’t tell me if they’re strings or lists… If the objects are lists, `df['anomaly_sequences'].explode()` should work, if they are strings look at this recent question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69397259 , then do `.explode()`

Comment: @Cimbali It prints: 0    [[2149, 2349], [4536, 4844], [3539, 3779]]
Name: anomaly_sequences, dtype: object

Comment: I missed why dont you use only `df['anomaly_sequences'].values`. It should already give you a nested list in an array.

Comment: @OnurOdabaşı It gives me the same output, a list with one element corresponding to the entire cell

Comment: Looks to me it's more about the type right? So you can do
`from ast import literal_eval` and `df["anomaly_sequences"] = df["anomaly_sequences"].apply(literal_eval)`. Edit: Just saw that @Cimbali already linked this answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure how you want to present your output, but if you want to convert your string into list of integers list, just do:

```
import json
var = "[[2149, 2349], [4536, 4844], [3539, 3779]]"
var = json.loads(var)
var

[[2149, 2349], [4536, 4844], [3539, 3779]]
```

And if you want to flatten the list of list, just use:

```
flat_list = [item for sublist in var for item in sublist]
flat_list

[2149, 2349, 4536, 4844, 3539, 3779]
```